# Flutter build IOS on windows

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I'm working on a flutter project and I want to build the IPA of my code using windows. I don't want to test the application in my windows I want just to build the IPA. Is it possible to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think its possible, you need to build that on MAC

Comment: Technically it is impossible. There is a reason nobody can make Xcode run on Windows (or Linux for that matter.) Even if you could build the IPA, coming from an iOS developer, you would have now way to install it onto a target device/upload to use on the app store. Your best bet (that isn't A: Illegal and B: Usable) is just to buy a Mac. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to generate an IPA from you windows machine is by using a CI/CD service like [Codemagic](https://codemagic.io/start/) using the steps described in this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667):

1. link your repository (Github, BitBucket , or Gitlab).
2. from settings > build for platforms > IOS
3. change the .app file you received to .zip and extract it.
4. You will find a file called Runner.app, put in a folder and compress it back.
5. change the extension from .zip to .ipa.

And here's your first IOS build without a Mac device.

Comment: yes, but you need a developer account in order to produce the IPA file.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot build a flutter iOS app directly from Windows. What you can do is use external tools to do it. One of these tools is Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI). It's a tool that let you access remote MacOS build machines.

It's pretty easy to use :

First install it by visiting the website

https://odevio.com/

Then setup your Apple Developer account with Odevio : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html

Finally you can build the app and retrieve the IPA in the build menu by creating an Ad Hoc build.

And that's it.